# How do damage upgrades of the same type stack?

Tags: dead-cells

When I pick up an upgrade scroll I can increase my attack power for brutality, tactic, or survival objects by 15%. How do damage increases of the same type stack with each other? Are they additive or multiplicative?

Comment: Are you asking about two of the same type (e.g. a second red after the first) or of different types (e.g. a green after a red)?

Comment: Two of the same type. Different types don't stack at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrades stack multiplicatively. The [wiki page for stats](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Stats?so=search#Damage_scaling) includes a table for the total damage bonus at each tier compared to base (level 1) stats and sample DPS values for a weapon.